# How do I calculate the amount of time per hour that table meets condition in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Apologies if I haven't give you the right format/break etiquette, I usually post python questions and it's quite easy to create dummy examples of the problem but my SQL skills aren't good enough to do so yet. Feedback much appreciated.

I have a running table in SQL which monitors the state of something running and records the start and end of running and stopped periods, as per below. The real table runs from a date in the past and will continue to do so into the future, and a status can last seconds, minutes, days, weeks, particularly stopped.

| Start | End | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 00:30:00.000 | Run |
| 2021-01-01 00:30:00.000 | 2021-01-01 10:30:00.000 | Stop |
| 2021-01-01 10:30:00.000 | 2021-01-02 10:00:00.000 | Run |
| 2021-01-02 10:00:00.000 | 2021-01-02 17:00:00.000 | Run |
| 2021-01-02 17:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 09:00:00.000 | Run |

What I need to get to is a calculation of the status per hour and the result table would look something like the below (but up to the current hour) for each hour start - it would return the amount of time in minutes (or seconds) that the machine is in each state per hour. Also, I don't particularly care about the 0s, but put them in for the example.

| Hour | Time in Status(mins) | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 30 | Run |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 30 | Stop |
| 2021-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 0 | Run |
| 2021-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 60 | Stop |
| ... |  |  |
| 2021-02-01 08:00:00.000 | 60 | Run |
| 2021-02-01 08:00:00.000 | 0 | Stop |

I can relatively easy calculate the current hours status (i.e. I could return that 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 had 30 mins run and 30 mins stop) but my knowledge let's me down when I try to add the remaining time to the next hour(s).

I'm working on SQL Server Management Studio on SQL Server 2017.

Comment: When do you want to start from? The beginning of the table?

Comment: And what do you do about missing hours?

Comment: The intention is to start from the beginning of the table but if it’s easier we can start on 01-01-2021 (not the real start of the table but what I used as an example). What do you mean about missing hours? There shouldn’t be any missing hours, only time periods where the machine is in stop mode for many hours.

Comment: Missing hours meaning they are not present in the table at all. And I have assumed in my answer that you would like `0` for any hours that have nothing for that status i.e. you still need a row with that hour and a tital of `0`, therefore we need an Hours table. If neither of these is true the we can remove the Hours table.

Comment: Ah I see, yes you're correct. Appreciate the solution; will try tomorrow and probably one back with some questions. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

For this, we can use an Hour table and left join your table to it, which we can generate on the fly using a tally table. I've used Itzik Ben-Gan's standard one here:

```sql
WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
    L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
    L3 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B ),
    Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
              FROM L3 ),
  Hours AS (
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(hour, @startDate, GETDATE()) + 1)
       DATEADD(hour, rownum - 1, @startDate) AS startHour,
       DATEADD(hour, rownum, @startDate) AS endHour
    FROM Nums
    ORDER BY rownum
  )

SELECT
    h.hour,
    v.Status,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(mi,
        CASE WHEN h.hour > t.Start THEN h.hour ELSE t.Start END,
        CASE WHEN h.hour < t.[End] THEN h.hour ELSE t.[End] END
    ))
FROM Hours h
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('Run'), ('Stop') ) v(Status)
LEFT JOIN myTable t
    ON t.Start < h.endHour AND t.[End] > h.startHour
    AND t.Status = v.Status
GROUP BY h.startHour, v.Status;
```

`DATEDIFF(min` will only give you whole minutes per row, so if you want to calculate fractions, use `DATEDIFF(ms` and divide it by `60000.0`

Comment: What is h.hour meant to be here? It doesn't look like you've defined it.

Comment: Sorry was meant to be `h.startHour`

Comment: I don't think this works as expected. For rows which have a time in myTable they all have a minus number (and pretty high - way higher than 60 mins...) and times which don't exist in the table have 0 in the column for both run and stop, even though the stop encompasses it.